# Appcelerator Titanium: Links/Images in Labels/TextArea - Open in WebView

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Is there a way to make URLs clickable in labels or textarea and open the link in a webview?
`TextArea` has the `autoLink` property but I don't know a way to handle clicks - safari is opened automatically on click.

Also I don't know how to add images to labels (smileys). I've seen many applications that use smileys in labels and textfields. Is this possible in Ti?

=> Are labels and textareas or other ways to display text completely text-only? (at least on iOS?) Are there any modules that add this functionality? I can't use `WebView`s every time I want to display a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple choices:

- Use web views, as you pointed out.
- Use the Styled Text modules for iOS and Android from Appcelerator. You'll need a subscription to get access to them.
- Make your own module that displays text with links in it, and customize what happens when the user touches a link.

The viability of these may change depending on where you want these links to show up, and what their parent will be (a view? a table view? etc).

Comment: Is there a place to read more about modules only available to Ti+ subscribers without being one myself? I'm a student and I can't afford the Indie plan however I'm interested in what I'm not able to use ;). Is the styled text module based on / comparable to TTStyledText (Three20)? Things like that should be free in Ti...

Comment: Yup, you can read about them here: http://www.appcelerator.com/products/plans-pricing/ Everything from "Titanium+Plus Starter Modules" down to "Analytics" are the modules that are available. It's also possible they'll be offered a la carte very soon so you don't have to have a subscription to get a module. The styled text module is based on NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium labels have an html attribute that renders HTML

Answer (score 0):

Titanium labels renders HTML code only in Android and WebMobile.

The best option it's to create a webview.